# Adding timedelta to datetime not moving to next day

Tags: python, datetime

If I run the following code in Python:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

just_before_midnight = datetime(2014, 7, 16, 11, 59, 59)
print(just_before_midnight)
skip_midnight = timedelta(seconds=2)
just_after_midnight_the_next_day = just_before_midnight + skip_midnight
print(just_after_midnight_the_next_day)
```

... it gives me the following output:

```
2014-07-16 11:59:59
2014-07-16 12:00:01
```

Can anyone explain why the date is the **16th** of July in both cases, instead of the second date being the **17th** of July?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the first time, `datetime(2014, 7, 16, 11, 59, 59)` is 11:59:59 AM, i.e. just before noon. Before midnight would be 23:59:59

```
>>> just_before_midnight = datetime(2014, 7, 16, 23, 59, 59)
>>> just_after_midnight_the_next_day = just_before_midnight + timedelta(seconds=2)
>>> print(just_before_midnight, just_after_midnight_the_next_day)
2014-07-16 23:59:59 2014-07-17 00:00:01
```